# Remove HTML tags except <a> and convert reserved to entities, keeping <a> in tact

Tags: php, email, html-entities, strip-tags

Using PHP, how can I remove all tags except anchors (`<a>`) from an HTML string, and then convert all the reserved characters into their HTML entities except for the  `<a>` tags?

For example, I would to convert this:

```
<p><a href="http://www.example.com/">Example.com</a> says that 5 < 6.</p>
```

into this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/">Example.com</a> says that 5 &lt; 6.
```

Comment: Use regex, check answer posted here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1736801/125551

Comment: Thanks for the link. I could replace the anchor with some string using that regex and put it back in after using strip_tags and htmlentities. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are the `<a>` tags ever parents of anything other than text nodes?

Comment: Possibly, which makes it even more difficult. I'm converting HTML email to text, so it could be anything inside the text node of the anchor. I could extract the links before stripping tags, place the hyperlink next to the closing anchor tag, and then strip tags, but that's not very nice looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org). [Click here for the demo which converts the original example](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php?filter%5BAutoFormat.AutoParagraph%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.Linkify%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveSpansWithoutAttributes%5D=0&filter%5BNull_CSS.AllowedProperties%5D=1&filter%5BCore.CollectErrors%5D=0&filter%5BHTML.Allowed%5D=a%5Bhref%7Ctitle%5D&filter%5BNull_HTML.Doctype%5D=1&filter%5BHTML.SafeObject%5D=0&filter%5BHTML.TidyLevel%5D=heavy&filter%5BURI.DisableExternalResources%5D=0&filter%5BNull_URI.Munge%5D=1&html=%3Cp%3E%3Ca%20href=%22http://www.example.com/%22%3EExample.com%3C/a%3E%20says%20that%205%20%3C%206.%3C/p%3E&submit=Submit) properly.

The code for doing this is:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Core.Encoding', 'UTF-8');
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'a[href]');
$filter = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$output = $filter->purify($input);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$str = '<p><a href="http://www.example.com/">Example.com</a> says that 5 < 6.</p>';
echo $str."\n";
$stripped = strip_tags($str, '<a>');
echo $stripped."\n";
```

Produces the output:

```
[stou$ ~]$ php hmm.php 
<p><a href="http://www.example.com/">Example.com</a> says that 5 < 6.</p>
<a href="http://www.example.com/">Example.com</a> says that 5 < 6.
[stou$ ~]$
```

**Edit:** Sorry missed your point about the html entities.

Comment: Thanks, but I need the less than sign in between the 5 and 6 to be `&lt;`.

Comment: It's ok, it was pretty subtle. :)